# Regressing on a variable, and then regressing the residuals on another variable

Tags: regression, self-study, regression-coefficients

Consider observations on three variables $X1, X2,$ and $X3$. Suppose that $X1$ is regressed on $X2$. When the residual of the above regression is regressed on $X3$, the regression coefficient of $X3$ is $β_3$. When $X1$ is regressed on $X2$ and $X3$ simultaneously, the regression coefficient of $X3$ is $β_3^*$.

We need to show that $|β_3| ≤ |β_3^*|$ and determine when equality holds.

A huge part of my confusion here is that I'm unsure how to perform the regression of the residuals on $X3$. If I could have any pointers on how to go about that, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: This statement is not generally true: I believe the inequality must go in the other direction.

Comment: Ahhhhh, checking again that was a (critical!) transcription error on my end. I'll edit the post. And thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Most multiple regression problems can be reduced to simple regressions involving one response variable and one explanatory variable (without an intercept), amounting to a plane geometry problem.**  The solution strategy presented here amounts to finding a particularly nice way to represent these variables.

The three variables in this question generate a Euclidean space of at most three dimensions.  We will solve the problem directly by selecting a simple but fully general way to express all the variables: that is, by choosing a suitable orthonormal basis for this space.  One basic computational fact, the *Normal equations* (for the simplest possible regression), is that

> the coefficient of the regression of one variable $Y$ against another nonzero variable $X$ is   $$\beta_{Y;X} = \frac{X\cdot Y}{X\cdot X}$$

where $\cdot$ is the Euclidean inner product.

Choosing units in which the length of $X_2$ (presumably nonzero) is $1,$ begin creating an orthonormal basis of which the first element is $X_2,$ so that in this basis $X_2 = (1,0,0).$

Because $\{X_2, X_3\}$ generate a subspace of at most two dimensions, we may select a second basis element to represent the second dimension, so that $X_3 = (u,v,0),$ say.

The regression of $X_1$ on $X_2$ and $X_3$ states

$$X_1 = \beta_2^* X_2 + \beta_3^* X_3 + \text{residual} = (\beta_2^* + \beta_3^*u,\ \beta_3^*v,\ w)$$

where the third basis element is chosen to be parallel to the residual $(0,0,w).$

**Consider the first two regressions.**  Regressing $X_1$ on $X_2=(1,0,0)$ simply picks out the first coefficient of $X_1,$ leaving the residual

$$E = (0, \beta_3^*v, w).$$

**Finally we come to the only step that requires any computation:** regressing $E$ against $X_3$ gives the coefficient

$$\beta_3 = \frac{E \cdot X_3}{X_3\cdot X_3} = \frac{(0,\beta_3^*v, w)\cdot(u,v,0)}{(u,v,0)\cdot(u,v,0)} = \beta_3^* \frac{v^2}{u^2+v^2}.$$

(We must assume $u^2+v^2\ne 0,$ which means $X_2$ is nonzero.  Otherwise, $X_2$ plays no role and trivially $\beta_3 = \beta_3^*.$)

Because both $u^2$ and $v^2$ are nonnegative, taking absolute values produces

> $$|\beta_3| = |\beta_3^*|\frac{v^2}{u^2 + v^2} \le |\beta_3^*|$$ with equality if and only if $u^2 = 0.$

In terms of the original variables, $u^2=0$ means $X_3 = (0,v,0)$ is orthogonal to $X_2.$

Answer (score 2):

Given the equation for the regression coefficients
$$
\hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y
$$
and the residuals
$$
R = Y-\hat Y =Y-X\hat\beta
$$
We get
$$
R=(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')Y
$$
The matrix $M= I-X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is sometimes called the "residual maker" because it turns $Y$ into $R$.

So, to perform a regression of the residuals on $X_3$, first get the residuals:
$$
R = (I-X_2(X_2'X_2)X_2')X1
$$
Then use this as the outcome in a regression on $X_3$ to get $\beta_3$:
\begin{align}
\hat\beta_3 &= (X_3'X_3)^{-1}X_3'R \\
&=(X_3'X_3)^{-1}X_3'(I-X_2(X_2'X_2)X_2')X_1
\end{align}

The real versions of these expressions would involve intercepts, but I omitted them for clarity (assuming all variables are mean centered).

Comment: You fall short of proving the stated result, which is a shame, because the result is false.

Comment: @whuber I just wanted to answer OP's main question, how to do a regression using the residuals, since this seemed like a homework assignment. I wouldn't know how to go about proving the claim they are supposed to evaluate.

Comment: Okay.  But that was really a subquestion formulated to make progress toward relating coefficients from different regression processes, $\beta_3$ and $\beta_3^*.$  In light of that it would be nice to offer formulas that make such relationships obvious or at least ease the task of comparing them.