# Why do the coefficients I get from `statsmodels` look to violate the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, python, statsmodels

As I understand it, the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem implies that if you regress y on x1 and x2, the coefficient on x2 will be the same as if you regress the residuals from regressing y on x1 on x2.

But if you run the below code, they're different. Why is this?

```
import random

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

random.seed(10)
target = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
x1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000) + 0.1 * target
x2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000) - 0.1 * target + 0.1 * x1

df_ = pd.DataFrame({'const': 1, 'x1': x1, 'x2': x2})
full_model = sm.OLS(target, df_).fit()
print('x2 coefficient in full model')
print(full_model.params['x2'].mean())

resid = sm.OLS(target, df_[['const', 'x1']]).fit().resid
partial_model = sm.OLS(resid, df_[['x2']]).fit()
print('x2 coefficient in full model')
print(partial_model.params['x2'].mean())
```

Comment: This has been thoroughly explored elsewhere here on CV.  See, for instance, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113207/919 (theoretical/geometrical) and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46508/919 (your approach), https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572623 (similar), https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32237/919 (another example), *etc.*